# How to insert data from two tables into listView?

Tags: android, listview, left-join, android-cursoradapter

I am using cursor adapter to get data from database. These two tables are joined with the `LEFT JOIN`.
I want to get data from the first table and show it in the first listViewItem, and the other listViewItems must be filled from the second table.

All this done mostly successful, but the reason I am here next:

e.g.
if each of two tables consist of 1 row, the listView will be show only 1 list item, but not two! if second table consist 2 rows, the listView will  show 2 listItems, but not 3 and the second listVIewItem will be information from second row of second table...

I have suspicion that my problem it this two table are joined but I have no idea how to fix this.
Please help.

**EDIT1:**

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        sDb = db;
        final String SQL_CREATE_USERS_INFO_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + UsersInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                " (" + UsersInfoEntry.USER_ID + " INTEGER, " +
                UsersInfoEntry.EMAIL + " TEXT, " +
                UsersInfoEntry.PHONE + " TEXT, " +
                UsersInfoEntry.FIRST_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                UsersInfoEntry.LAST_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                UsersInfoEntry.SEX + " INTEGER, " +
                UsersInfoEntry.DATE_OF_BIRTH + " TEXT, " +
                " FOREIGN KEY (" + UsersInfoEntry.USER_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
                UsersInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" + UsersInfoEntry.USER_ID +" ), " +
                " UNIQUE ( " + UsersInfoEntry.USER_ID + " ) ON CONFLICT REPLACE );";

final String SQL_CREATE_TABLE_NEWS_TAPE = "CREATE TABLE " + NewsTapeEntry.TABLE_NAME +
                " (" + NewsTapeEntry.NEWS_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                NewsTapeEntry.USER_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                NewsTapeEntry.CONTENT + " TEXT, " +
                NewsTapeEntry.CREATED_AT + " TEXT, " +

                " FOREIGN KEY (" + NewsTapeEntry.NEWS_ID + ") REFERENCES " +
                NewsTapeEntry.TABLE_NAME + " (" + NewsTapeEntry.NEWS_ID + "), " +
                " UNIQUE (" + NewsTapeEntry.NEWS_ID + ") ON CONFLICT REPLACE);";
}

static {
        sProfileWithNewsBuilder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        sProfileWithNewsBuilder.setTables(
                UsersInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME + " LEFT JOIN " +
                        NewsTapeEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ON " +
                        UsersInfoEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + UsersInfoEntry.USER_ID + " = " +
                        NewsTapeEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + NewsTapeEntry.USER_ID
}
```

Comment: By using a **join** you are merging two tables into one. They will behave like one table. Can we see your table structure and the join query you are using?

Comment: @Hindol , hi!
I updated my question, take a look please.

Comment: Your update helps but I am still not very clear about what content you want in you first and second ListView, can you please explain a bit?

Comment: @Hindol, idea was the next: in first listViewItem - show information about user (from first table), the other listViewItems - his news (second table, joined with first table cos need to get name  etc

Comment: Sorry, I am out of ideas.